# How to verify a .Onion domain against a private key

Tags: cryptography, rsa, private-key, deep-web

I am working on a project that will basically sell .Onion (TOR) domain names.
The process of generating the domains is similar to mining bitcoins - RSA private keys are generated en mass and if one randomly matches something in my wordlist - then it gets saved off somewhere and added to a database.

The problem here is that this is still a slow process to do solo - so in order for me to try and make it a collaborate exercise - I want to create an online API / Rest API that will allow people to upload their domains and private keys for them to sell on the site.

The problem is  - I don't quite know how to verify their domain name against the private key.

Eg:
They would be providing a domain like

abcdabcdabcdabcd.onion

and the key would be:
    `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIICXQIBAAKBgQCb+wlPxR8VoUJsYcEFsPX+LfB3jorW9QlH1N38itQvMs0RyTCB
    +c7hfYQH2f8Z67lobWvveYct51ykhB8n3AluMYIF3OxGlmQJuMIFQmKFryLexzPj
    LEPREB7+KmeL9Sx1sL4a2Z0qJL4501Ij0T5C3cDEMOvUQBpBttpuUbj1RQIEZTIY
    AQKBgBwWDEMOYKaSO17xJRuf32CDYJcDKtkJ1GlWROHxREo68J+74DqF55rnoYl/
    4OkfjUMA2WjjjASVRmviBD79vni3eB9MFNzDEMOYa6EIyo1vDEMOzEnfrszkPGEj
    vOCHbDiG/FlZsCKsADEMOEAuAUQ3W8669Du4FrO9/al+1IudhAkEAy+KBk8HFsO8Z
    UttdlsLt8//l+NbEMmWF/I588EGyYWUuPUVJd5Xv6iSaDMdecjeW/xf4Wja5C91n
    lCfb/lxhsQJBAMPZ2fzcUpyKhk6JretSyoq0iVQCO5Pn/0QwTwRUbKreXnnVBYY+
    uco2ocfRwsmVK4LUwPgict5qw10bZfl8vdUCQATUV/S0zNc+DEMOw/7p5oJk5hwa
    +Hrhcf5aVw1AOqySGs0e9V+qDYIjrbkg/BDEMOD00bTTV9a9h3poFrm+DEMOQF2t
    lgqYbgDEMOZbE+PgebFB6swKfx9Px7+PnNsBK+Mld6pRyldfQ2DEMOr/cy4JQDYA
    oyX51SNWUMJzkYgeMEUCQQC8i6b3e06B9+++NGADEMO9F5KhlDr1wwSQqnNccDX5
    N5vnlhJ/0DGxIMm/bP1ZPUK4/bmvKjNYd7D8zuz2cPor
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Could someone point me in the direction of some .Net code that can take a private key, and verify that the domain also provided is authentic?
https://github.com/lachesis/scallion
This github project (one of the tools I use - has the code to 'generate' the domains and private keys - I am just not sure how to perform the verification after the fact)

Comment: What is the value of a PRIVATE KEY if someone else also know it?

Comment: The private key verifys ownership of a .Onion domain - it makes impersonation impossible unless someone else has the exact same private key.
Therefore - there is a relationship between the .Onion domain name, and the private key.
The people visiting your .Onion domain do NOT know your private key, just your public .Onion domain address.

Comment: Why do you need their private key? They can just sign a text with their private key. Then, you can verify that they own that private key based on their public key. But in your question, it seems you need them to send their private key.

Comment: I don't actually care how I do the verification - All I need is some working code that can verify that the domain that they are supplying has a valid PrivateKey.
Plus - if they are wanting to distribute the domain from the website I am making - the private key will have to be held in the database at some point in order to e-mail it to the person buying it.
Ideally - I would like a method that basically does this:
bool IsValid(string domain, string privatekey)
I just want to know if the private key supplied matches the domain.
If something else can be supplied in place of the private key, cool

Comment: To do this securely you need to split the private key, one part is only known to the person who want to own the domain, and the miner only varies some parts, e.g. the public exponent or a third prime factor.

Comment: "If you decide to run a hidden service Tor generates an ​RSA-1024 keypair. The .onion name is computed as follows: first the ​SHA1 hash of the ​DER-encoded ​ASN.1 public key is calculated. Afterwards the first half of the hash is encoded to ​Base32 and the suffix ".onion" is added. Therefore .onion names can only contain the digits 2-7 and the letters a-z and are exactly 16 characters long."

Comment: I have read that- unfortunately I am looking for a c# implementation that can verify a private or public key in relation to the domain.

Comment: So find a DER library (perhaps BouncyCastle supports it) and encode the public key that way. Once you have encoded the pub key, you can encode its SHA1 hash with Base32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never got an answer for this, but I did find a way, using Scallions on source code to verify a Private Key against an Onion Address.

```
RSAWrapper rsaWrapper = new RSAWrapper("d:\\pk.txt");
Console.WriteLine(rsaWrapper.OnionHash);
```

Not ideal - as it requires the private key.
Inside the RSAWrapper - it does some unsafe code to do 'something' to the public key to determine a DER encoded value.
This is the important part of getting the onion address.

```
public string OnionHash
        {
            get {
                return tobase32str(this.get_der_hash(),10);
            }
        }

private byte[] get_der_hash()
        {
            var sha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed();
            return sha1.ComputeHash(this.DER);
            //return tobase32str(hash);
        }


public byte[] DER {
            get {
                byte[] der;
                int buf_size = Rsa.Size + 100;
                int size = 0;
                unsafe // must be a better way to do this!
                {
                    IntPtr hglob = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buf_size);
                    void* ptr = hglob.ToPointer();
                    void** ptr2 = &ptr;

                    size = Native.i2d_RSAPublicKey(Rsa.Handle, (byte**)ptr2);
                    if(size > buf_size)
                        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("DER was too large!");

                    der = new byte[size];
                    Marshal.Copy(hglob,der,0,size);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(hglob);
                }
                return der;
            }
        }
```

Edit - Woot :
Looks like the RSAWrapper class is very cohesive and modular.
I was able to copy it out - it only needs access to the OpenSSL library, and it also has an RSA.FromPublicKey(string s); method for creating the RSA.

So now, I am able to do

```
    RSAWrapper rsaWrapper = new RSAWrapper("d:\\pubkey.txt", true);
    Console.WriteLine(rsaWrapper.OnionHash);
```

Took a few months - but got a better answer than I set out to get.
Now I can take public keys, and verify that the Onion address matches the public key. This would verify ownership of an Onion address, without the risk of having to send a private key across the network.